# With CMake, how can I produce an error during 'make install' and still run later install steps?

Tags: cmake

How do I produce an install error and still execute later `make install` steps?

Typically with CMake, I would use `message(SEND_ERROR "error message")` to create an error and continue running later steps.  However, when I insert this into cmake_install.cmake using an `install(CODE ...)` instruction, then the same line immediately aborts execution of `make install` and does not execute later steps.

Under CMake 2.8.7, I was asked to update a custom install step to continue the rest of the installation.  My client has a MATLAB install step that fails on certain systems and wants to mitigate the impacts for developers while they decide how to proceed.  In the examples below I have replaced "matlab" "args" with "touch" "/dev/null/cannot/exist" so anybody should be able to reproduce the problem ([example project](https://github.com/ransage/code_samples/blob/master/cmake/install_errors/CMakeLists.txt)).

**Specific issue**

I can successfully insert something into the `make install` instructions that are written into cmake_install.cmake using:

```
  install(CODE "execute_process (                                                                                                                                            
        COMMAND \"touch\" \"/dev/null/cannot/exist\"                                                                                                                         
        ERROR_VARIABLE _err                                                                                                                                                  
        RESULT_VARIABLE _res                                                                                                                                                 
  )                                                                                                                                                                          
  if (NOT \${_res} EQUAL \"0\")                                                                                                                                              
    message( SEND_ERROR \"err: \${_err}, res: \${_res}\")                                                                                                                    
    message( INFO \" Proceeding with any remaining steps, but 'make install' will fail\")                                                                                    
  endif ()"
    COMPONENT mycomponentname
  )
```

This results in the following in cmake_install.cmake:

```
IF(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT OR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}" STREQUAL "mycomponentname")
  execute_process (
        COMMAND "touch" "/dev/null/cannot/exist"
        ERROR_VARIABLE _err
        RESULT_VARIABLE _res
  )
  if (NOT ${_res} EQUAL "0")
    message( SEND_ERROR "err: ${_err}, res: ${_res}")
    message( INFO " Proceeding with any remaining steps, but 'make install' will fail")
  endif ()
ENDIF(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT OR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}" STREQUAL "mycomponentname")
```

**Resulting output**

```
[previous output]
...
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:82 (message):
  err: touch: cannot touch `/dev/null/cannot/exist': Not a directory

  , res: 1


make: *** [install] Error 1

real    0m3.041s
user    0m1.660s
sys     0m0.436s
```

Note: it aborts immediately, not even executing the next INFO message line.

Comment: Won't `message(STATUS "error message")` do?

Comment: To me "produce an install error" means that `make install` returns with non-zero return value